# How to use Serilog for error logging in a .NET Standard 1.4 class library

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.5, serilog, .net-standard

I am working with .NET Framework 4.5.2 project. I am creating a class library and I want to use Serilog for error logging in this class library. However, since this is a class library, how do I initialize the logger to begin with?

I am familiar with initializing the actual logger with something similar to this

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.RollingFile(new CompactJsonFormatter(), 
                             @"C:\AppLog\log.json")
    .CreateLogger();
```

But how/where do I call that initialization code? Does Serilog work like Log4Net where it needs to be initially called from a console, desktop or similar program that uses the class library?  Or is Serilog capable of being set up entirely from within the class library?

I have used Serilog with .NET Core solutions before where I can initialize the logger in Startup.cs and then easily use Dependency Injection to inject the logger into the constructors of the class library. But the project I am working on now is .NET 4.x, without the .NET Core DI framework.

These class libraries I am creating will be used by a WCF Service Library (which itself looks just like a class library) and the WCF Service Library will then be hosted by IIS 8 for production. So, do I need to configure Serilog in the IIS web.Config and then instance the logger in something like the Application Start in the global.aspx?

Thanks in advance for any help.